# What is the fastest/most performant SQL driver for Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I know of PyMySQLDb, is that pretty much the thinnest/lightest way of accessing MySql?

Comment: I would bet that the DB disk accesses, network I/O, and the act of computing the answer to a query are going to be far more expensive than overhead imposed by the SQL driver.

Comment: I agree with @Thanatos. If MySQL is a given, then mind the database design and optimization, and use the most convenient driver for Python.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest is SQLAlchemy.

"Say what!?"

Well, a nice ORM, and I like SQLAlchemy, **you will get your code finished much faster**. If your code then runs 0.2 seconds slower isn't really gonna make any noticeable difference. :)

Now if you get performance problems, then you can look into improving the code. But choosing the access module after who in theory is "fastest" is premature optimization.

Comment: If your code then runs 0.2 seconds slower isn't really gonna make any "noticeable difference" - do you benchmark ?

Comment: so a query that takes 50ms to run now has to take 250ms? maybe this is acceptable for some use cases, but not all.

Comment: @RussBradberry: The answer to your question is "It won't take 250ms."

Comment: SQL Alchemy is not a database driver. It's an extra layer on top

Answer (score 3):

The lightest possible way is to use ctypes and directly call into the MySQL API, of course, without using any translation layers. Now, that's ugly and will make your life miserable unless you also write C, so yes, the MySQLDb extension is the standard and most performant way to use MySQL while still using the Python Database API. Almost anything else will be built on top of that or one of its predecessors.

Of course, the connection layer is rarely where all of the database speed problems come from. That's mostly from misusing the API you have or building a bad database or queries.

Answer (score 0):

MySQLDb is faster while SQLAlchemy makes code more user friendly -:)